# Simplify SQL query rather than using Joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run a code that looks like the below. The subquery in this pulls from the same table as the main query - the only constraint is column3 is/is not NULL.
Is there any way to simplify it?

```
SELECT a.column1, a.column2, b.column1, b.column2
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT column1, column2
  FROM table1
  WHERE column3 IS NULL) b
ON a.column4 = b.column4
WHERE a.column3 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a.column1, a.column2, b.column1, b.column2
```

Comment: In your query you've missed the ON clause (in INNER JOIN you must specifiy ON clause).

Comment: mm i'm sorry. i meant to include it. is there still a way to simplify it?

Comment: simplify? in terms of readability or performance?

Comment: in terms of performance. say, can i use a case when clause here?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do here.  You are trying to INNER JOIN cases where column 3 is NULL with cases where it is NOT NULL? I would think you would always get an empty data set.  Maybe this would be clearer if you can gave sample data and meaningful column names.

Comment: since we're essentially running the same table twice, which would slow down the query time

Comment: hey Mike, so what i'm getting is a different set of data for columns 1 & 2 when column 3 is either NULL or not NULL

Answer (score 2):

After your edit: (in your query b table has not a column4)

Try this:

```
SELECT a.column1, a.column2, b.column1, b.column2
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table1 b
ON a.column4 = b.column4
WHERE a.column3 IS NULL
AND b.column3 IS NOT NULL
```

If you think you have duplicate among four columns you can use GROUP BY or DISTINCT command in field list.

Comment: Hey Joe thanks for simplifying it. I have a question: Does it still query table1 twice? If so, is there a way to make it run faster?

Comment: You must query twice table1 because you want know four fields (a.column1, a.column2, b.column1, b.column2), where the first two columns respect condition of column3 is null and the other two fields respect condition column3 is not null